# What considerations are important for initial placements in Kingdom Builder?

Tags: kingdom-builder

I've only played Kingdom Builder a few times.  What should I be looking for when placing my first couple settlements?  Are there synergies between the scoring rules and bonus abilities to consider?  How much should I avoid being adjacent to multiple terrains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first turn is basically a trade-off between getting the best bonus tile (given the scoring goals in play) and minimising the risk of getting trapped, by avoiding placing in a large area of one terrain and making as few adjacencies as possible. It's often possible to do this in such a way that the bonus tile you claim guarantees you another tile next turn, regardless of your card draw.

Answer (score 0):

Place according to the 3 endgame win cards. But generally keep your options open for expansion by starting with small areas you can fill up quick.