# Initial card house rule for Kingdom Builder

Tags: house-rules, openings, kingdom-builder

I noticed in Kingdom Builder that the later players have a noticeable disadvantage if they have a card for the same terrain, because there is usually only one good spot to start with (see [the question on initial placements](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7808)), and that will be taken.

Therefore I have suggested and played with this rule:

> During the first round, if you draw a card with a terrain that one of the players before you has had already, you draw again.

I did not play it often enough for it to occur often enough to assess whether this helps, and whether later player still have a too-large disadvantage. Have you tried that or similar rules before, and how did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do if I wanted to avoid this:

At the start of the game, remove one card of each terrain type, shuffle and give each person a card.  Shuffle the remaining cards back into the deck.

This will guarantee everyone has a unique starting terrain.

Answer (score 4):

My groups have enjoyed having players always have two terrains from which to choose.  When you play one draw to replace it.

Comment: Only in the first round, or throughout the game?
(Side remark: Just got Kingdom Builder for Christmas :-))

Comment: Throughout the game actually.  I've seen so many games where players end up with the same terrain over and over and they have little hope in that case.  The problem which your final player faces will face all players throughout the game.  The two card solution reduces the feeling of being screwed by luck.  Of course the downside is analysis paralysis.

Comment: At least with this variant, you know that (and when) you will have two of the same terrain type coming up, and can plan accordingly. Strongly recommend, and wish this were an option in the app.